# Density of sum of two independent uniform variables with different intervals

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

X and Y are two independent uniform random variables with ranges [0,α] and [0,β], respectively (β>α).

How can I calculate the pdf of Z, when Z is the sum these two independent random variables (i.e., Z=X+Y)?

Comment: The graph of the pdf looks like a trapezoid.

Comment: This question needs more context. There is a nice formula for computing the PDF of the sum  of *any* two continuous random variables: $$ f_Z(z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,z-x) \;dx.$$ Where are you having trouble applying it here?

Comment: See (for example) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357672/), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/895075/), and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254802/).

Answer (score 1):

**Comment** (outline and visualization): For $\alpha = 5,\,\beta = 10$ here is a histogram (blue bars) of
a large random sample from the distribution of $Z,$ showing @kimchilover's
trapezoid. The joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is the uniform distribution
over a rectangle with density $f_{X,Y}(x,y).$ When you work out the limits on the integral (split into three parts) in @spaceisdarkgreen's Comment, you will get the PDF of $Z$ (red line).

[image]